# Passing argument by r-value reference to constructor that accept const ref

Tags: c++

I got a dispute with my colleague.
We have following example:

```
class Key
{
public:
    Key() {}
    Key(Key&& ) {}
    Key(const Key& ) {}
};

class KeyWrapper
{
public:
    KeyWrapper(const Key& key) : _key(key) {}
    
private:
    Key _key;
};

int main()
{
    Key key;
    KeyWrapper wrapper(std::move(key));

    return 0;
}
```

My point that in line `KeyWrapper wrapper(std::move(key));`  std::move has no effect, because KeyWrapper constructor accepts const ref and therefore std::move can be omitted. And inside of this constructor we can't write _key(std::move(key)), because we have constant reference to input parameter.

But my colleague says that std::move() should be in line `KeyWrapper wrapper(std::move(key));`  and also we should write _key(std::move(key)).

Please, judge us...

Comment: Why not just [try it](https://godbolt.org/z/rPcWW6Eco)? Also, writing the question up as a dispute between you and a colleague serves no purpose. Please try to ask a clear and specific question instead of adding unrelated info to it.

Comment: Moves both in `main` and the member-initializer would make sense if KeyWrapper were constructed as `KeyWrapper(Key key)` (which it isn't).

Comment: I'm with Clang-Tidy: "Passing result of std::move() as a const reference argument; no move will actually happen"

Comment: `std::move` never have any effect by itself. It only adjust the return type. The effect come from the overload function selected afterward.

Comment: @hshsvagen You are right, and your colleague is wrong. A const reference can bind to both an lvalue and an rvalue, but you can't move data from a const reference. So there is no point in using `std::move()` in this code at all, the `Key(Key&&)` constructor will not be called.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take.

If logically a move is the proper thing to do at the call site (in this case main()), you should move it.  If the code receiving the object does not handle moves, reverting to c++98-style copies, that's a valid implementation of a move (but not optimized.)  There is still no problem.  Down the road, if the object begins accepting rvalue references or gains a forwarding-ref interface, you will benefit from the move improvements without having to go back and fix your calling code to take advantage of the change.

However, in a function receiving `key` as a `const &`, it should **never** move its argument.  There is no justification for this, because you do not know anything about the caller, and cannot assume it is a safe thing to do.

Some classes are "safe to use after move" because move does not actually modify the source object, however, relying on this is really a bad idea as it depends on implementation details that are subject to change without warning, and is really just doing it wrong.

Here's some guidelines for when to move or not:

- If a function receives an lvalue reference, it must never `move` it
- If a function receives an object by value, it is safe to `move`
- If a function receives an rvalue reference, it is safe to `move`
- If a function receives a "forwarding reference" (a template function taking T&&) then it is **not safe** to `move`, but *is* safe to `forward`.

Notice, the rules above do not change based on knowledge that the underlying type is known to have identical behavior when moved and copied.  For example, a trivial `class` containing only primitive data is technically safe to move even from a const& because moving it doesn't modify the source. However, *do not do that* because it has no benefit and is depending on something you might not control (or realize has changed.)  It also make it look as though you are confused about move semantics, and will cause people to doubt the robustness of the rest of the design.

If you are in a controlled environment where you intimately know the caller and callee code are working together, and they are private without outside code using them, you may feel safe to relax some of these rules--but I still do not recommend it because it's harder to reason about when your code does odd things that break convention, and there is still little/no benefit.